# Difference between flame test and ability to show photoelectric effect

Tags: light

My textbook says magnesium doesn't give flame test. But it also says that it is a good photoelectric material. Are both concepts using "visible" light to remove or excite electrons?  What is the basic difference between these two and why is magnesium showing only one of them?

Comment: It is not the only factor to be thought of to explain the colour for a proper flame test we need to add ${HCl}$ to the compound and heat it to the flame.You may refer this https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/1_s-Block_Elements/Group__1%3A_The_Alkali_Metals/2Reactions_of_the_Group_1_Elements/Flame_Tests

Comment: why do we need to add hcl? What is the differnce caused by it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misconception. Observing an emission spectrum and photoelectric effects are different things. Photoelectric effect requires not only the electron is ejected with some kinetic energy, but it is ejected by *light* of a suitable wavelength. No heat or flame is involved.

In (Bunsen burner) flame emission spectroscopy, your temperature is not high enough to remove electrons from Mg atoms in the gas phase. Eventually, the flame temperatures can be made high enough that you do start to observe emission from Mg atoms, but it is in the UV range. Your eyes cannot see UV light.

Comment: we use visible light for excitation in photoelectric effect right? Or UV rays?

Comment: You can use visible or UV light. It only depends on the $work function$ of the metal i.e. how easy it is to eject an electron from a metal.